# Converting non-numeric matrix into numeric

Tags: r, matrix, numeric, r-sp

I have an imported table with longitudes and latitudes and want to create a spatial grid from them.
The coordinates are in this format:

```
[1] 6.955 6.937 6.956 6.923
```

So looks numeric for me. But trying to create the grid this Error occurs:

> Error in .local(obj, ...) :
>         cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix

When I try to change the format using as.numeric I get this result:

```
[1] 10  9  6  8
```

How can I convert the coordinates in numeric format without changing the value?

---

```
longitude = structure(c(9L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 
7L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("6.920", 
"6.922", "6.923", "6.924", "6.926", "6.936", "6.937", "6.939", 
"6.955", "6.956", "6.958"), class = "factor")

latitude = structure(c(10L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 
9L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("50.911", 
"50.918", "50.920", "50.929", "50.930", "50.931", "50.934", "50.950", 
"50.965", "50.969"), class = "factor")
```

---

The original table `luftdaten.set` contains latitudes, longitudes and particulate matter values. I tried to created a grid:

```
coordinates(luftdaten.set) <- ~ latitude + longitude
```

I also tried to create a dataframe with only the coordinates and tried to derive a grid from it:

```
luftdaten.grid <- data.frame(latitude, longitude) 
luftdaten.grid <- data.frame(latitude, longitude)
```

Both throws the described error.

`coordinates` is in the SpatialTools 'sp' package.

Comment: What's the current type given by `str`? If it's factor, you need to do `as.numeric(as.character(...))` to get convert the labels to number instead of grabbing the integers as which they're represented internally.

Comment: check the`class` of the columns whether it is factor , if it is using `as.numeric (as.character(your column))`

Comment: The result of dput(mat) for my data is:

> dput(longitude)
structure(c(9L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 
7L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 11L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("6.920", 
"6.922", "6.923", "6.924", "6.926", "6.936", "6.937", "6.939", 
"6.955", "6.956", "6.958"), class = "factor")
> dput(latitude)
structure(c(10L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 
9L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("50.911", 
"50.918", "50.920", "50.929", "50.930", "50.931", "50.934", "50.950", 
"50.965", "50.969"), class = "factor")

Comment: I tried using the as.numeric (as.character(your column)) expression, but it still return the same error message

Comment: `longitude <- as.numeric(as.character(longitude))` seems to work in converting to numeric. However, if at a later stage you are still receiving an error, you should also show this code.

Comment: okay, thanks @Moo. Can you edit your question with additional code and include packages please.

Comment: using your data: `luftdaten.set = data.frame(longitude=as.numeric(as.character(longitude)),
               latitude=as.numeric(as.character(latitude))) ; 
coordinates(luftdaten.set) <- ~ longitude  + latitude` proceeds without error. (although i can't say whether this is sensible)

Comment: Thx to all! In combination it works!

Answer (score 2):

That way it works:

```
longitude <- as.numeric(as.character(longitude))
latitude <- as.numeric(as.character(latitude))
luftdaten.grid <- data.frame(latitude, longitude)
attach(luftdaten.grid)
coordinates(luftdaten.grid) <- ~ latitude + longitude
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to get a matrix where each row is a lat/long pair:

```
as.matrix(cbind(as.numeric(as.character(latitude)),
                as.numeric(as.character(longitude))))

        [,1]  [,2]
 [1,] 50.969 6.955
 [2,] 50.965 6.937
 [3,] 50.931 6.956
 [4,] 50.950 6.923
 [5,] 50.911 6.939
 [6,] 50.930 6.924
 [7,] 50.920 6.936
 [8,] 50.918 6.922
 [9,] 50.934 6.958
[10,] 50.950 6.920
[11,] 50.929 6.926
[12,] 50.969 6.955
[13,] 50.965 6.937
[14,] 50.931 6.956
[15,] 50.950 6.923
[16,] 50.911 6.939
[17,] 50.930 6.924
[18,] 50.920 6.936
[19,] 50.918 6.922
[20,] 50.934 6.958
[21,] 50.950 6.920
[22,] 50.929 6.926
```

Comment: Thx, but obviously the coordinates-function does not work with a matrix. It then throws following error message:

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates<-’ for signature ‘"matrix"’